# devcontainer on Windows mounts empty directory while docker-compose mounts everything correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-compose, docker-volume, vscode-devcontainer, mounted-volumes

Here are my definitions:

- structure:

```
.devcontainer
  devcontainer.json
docker
  bot
    Dockerfile
    entrypoint.sh
  docker-compose.base.yaml
  docker-compose.dev.yaml
pdm.lock
...
```

- `devcontainer.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "SomeName",
  "dockerComposeFile": [
    "../docker/docker-compose.base.yml",
    "../docker/docker-compose.dev.yml",
  ],
  "service": "bot",
  "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
  "workspaceFolder": "/mounted",
}
```

- `docker-compose.base.yaml` (the `dev` one is currently just empty `services: {}`):

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  bot:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/bot/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '../:/mounted'
    restart: unless-stopped
```

- `Dockerfile`:

```bash
FROM python:3.11.5

WORKDIR /mounted

ENV PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION ignore
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  nano \
  vim \
  grc \
  git \
  htop \
  iptraf \
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN pip install -U pip pdm && pdm sync

COPY docker/bot/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

The build of the container fails on `pdm sync` command, which requires `pdm.lock` to be mounted and present. And it is mounted normally when using `docker-compose up` directly.

When I added directory listing:

```
RUN pip install -U pip pdm && ls -a && pdm sync
```

that reported only `.` and `..` as options, so `/mounted` is empty.

Why is the volume not mounted correctly? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You need to mount at build time. Or move `pdm sync` to entrypoint.sh

Comment: try adding volumes top-level element: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/07-volumes/

Comment: @Mate (oops deleted previous comment accidentally, readding) thanks, but why does it work with Compose and not devcontainer? Is it related to context? How can I mount at build time with devcontainer or use the same context?

Comment: As for named volume, they don't work too well on Windows for me unfortunately, so far: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13704

Comment: Windows issues -.- . I never tried, but check this: https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-local-file-mount